# How to send information from application to dll

Tags: delphi

I wanted to learn how to use plugins application in Delphi. I know how to send information from the plugin to form in application but i dont know how to send information from application to dll. Can someone help me and tell how do it?

My current code:
**DLL:**

```
library Plugin;
uses Windows;

procedure SomeText(var S: WideString); stdcall;
begin
S := 'Some text abc';
end;

exports
SomeText;
```

**EXE:**

```
type
TSomeText = procedure(var S: WideString); stdcall;

var
SomeText: TSomeText;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
DLL : THandle;
begin
DLL := LoadLibrary('plugin.dll');
try
@SomeText := GetProcAddress(DLL, 'SomeText');
if @SomeText=nil then raise Exception.Create('Error');
SomeText(S);
Edit1.Text := S;
finally
FreeLibrary(DLL);
end;
end;
```

And this code works correctly. The text 'Some text' is displayed in a edit1 on a form. But how to do it the other way? The text from the edit1 was displayed on the edit1 on the form of a plugin. I would ask for an example of how to do it.
Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Usually using callback functions.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There are several available plugin libraries, including the one in the open source JEDI JVCL, that will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When `SomeText` receives `S`, simply have it assign the text to the plugin's edit control.

Comment: if both application and program would be written with the same Delphi - then use BPL (package) not DLL. That is how Delphi IDE and VCL is built itself.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I don't know how to do it. My 'S' get text from DLL [edit1, label1 etc.] and shows in EXE [in edit1 or something else] but I wan't get text from EXE [from Edit1, label1, memo1 etc.] and shows in DLL in component Edit1. Picture one work's in my code. Picture two i don't know how to do it... [link](http://imgur.com/a/1xuiy) This is my first time to building plugins with EXE so please help me. Any tips on how to do it, example, anything... Thank you.

Comment: Your code already sends information in both directions via the var parameter. Your question is very imprecise.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thank you... ofc... var... now all work's ok.

DLL:
`procedure SomeText2(var S: WideString); stdcall;
begin
frmDLL.Edit1.Text := 'Some text abc';
end;`

EXE:
`S := Form1.Edit1.Text;
SomeText2(S);`